# Should the "lists of works" close reason be updated?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Here's our current close reason for asking about lists of works:

> Requests for lists of **works or recommendations** are off-topic as they do not fit our [questions and answers format](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about). Feel free to ask about people's favorites in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

There are a couple of problems with this close reason:

1. It links to a frozen chat room which has been renamed to "Poisoned room; it is defunct." — not the best place to link newcomers.
2. The phrase "questions and answers format" links to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about which redirects to the site's tour page. That *is* a good place to link newcomers, and it does mention what kind of questions are OK to ask, but perhaps one of these would be a better and more specific page to link to:

   - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
   - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

---

The technical issues of the correct URL for meta and using HTTPS instead of HTTP are addressed in:

[Minor technical issues with off-topic close box](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11002/19561)

Comment: Good catch, I'm all for this.

Comment: Quick point, the chat link for new users, (and anyone under 10k rep?) just leads to a page not found result rather than abnything about a poisoned chat room.

Answer (score 10):

1. **Yes**
   We should point to the new chat room.
2. **Maybe**
   Perhaps the best option would be to create a clean, canonical question-answer pair on meta, tag it with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), and then point to *that*.

Comment: 1. Should we remove the link to the chat room wholesale (given our "history") or should we just update it to market the room as newbie-friendly now that we have a clean slate? 2. Good idea.

Comment: Chat requires 20 rep to participate.  Closing a newcomer's question, inviting them to ask it in chat, and then telling them "Sorry, you're not allowed to do that until you ask *good* questions" is kind of... rude.