# Minor technical issues with off-topic close box

Tags: support, feature-request, closing-questions

There are some minor technical issues with the off-topic close reasons, which should be trivial to fix.

[image: Off topic close reasons]

1. All links are HTTP instead of HTTPS. This includes the migration option to meta.
2. The link to meta from "scientific explanations" uses the old URL; `meta.scifi` should become `scifi.meta`.

---

The question of where to link is addressed in

[Should the "lists of works" close reason be updated?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11000/19561)

---

Apparently, the issue isn't as simple as I thought. And we need a dev. See:

- [Links in close reasons are (sometimes?) still HTTP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295054/239016)
- [Migration to meta still uses old met URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296932/239016)

Comment: As this bug presumably exists on every SE site which has custom off-topic close reasons, perhaps you should post this on [meta.se] to more quickly draw a dev's attention? (We the mods could change all the links manually, but I'd rather make as few as possible of these changes. We can't edit existing close reasons, so we'd need to deactivate them and create new ones, which would mess up the stats; also, it needs two mods, one to propose the 'new' close reason and one to approve it.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah, okay, will do. I thought a mere edit was needed.

Comment: [If only.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186336/278659)

Comment: Meh, they all get redirected to the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed <s>— mostly</s>.

1. All links are now either explicitly https or protocol-relative.
2. The link to our policy on "scientific explanations" now points to `https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7364`.

Comment: Argh. Most of the links have become `https` as you say, but the "help center" link in the generic off-topic close reason is still `http`.

Comment: Seems to be [meta-tag:status-completed] now, @Randal'Thor.